# How to call method from viewModel in service Android?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

I got a service

```
class BubbleButtonService : Service(), View.OnTouchListener, View.OnClickListener
```

In that service I got a method that I want to call a method from the viewModel. I was trying to pass viewModel through the constructor but it does not work the Manifest does not see this service and gives an error

```
This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)
```

So how can I do that method from service call method from view model or update view model live data?

Answer (score 1):

A ViewModel exists after someone has instantiated it and it's usually done from an Activity or Fragment.
If your method (in ViewModel's class-file) is a STATIC one, then you can declare it as "public static" and it will be visible from everywhere.
If it is a class-method, then you have to:

1. instantiate its ViewModel
2. choose how the Service will "reach" it:

   - (worst way) save ViewModel instance in a static variable and use it from the Service...
   - ...or bind() Activity to the Service, pass ViewModel as argument/parameter, save it in a Service's variable and finally use it in your Service

However it's not good pratice calling ViewModel methods directly from Services (expecially if it's an IntentService or a Background Service).